# Why is there erased old data in this Map?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have this code. So, I don't understand why 
erased old data in the hash map - in result.put(name, localMap)

```
class FilterServers  {

     // In this class, we filter our servers on our key word

    static Map <String, Map <String, String>>
    getValues(String keyWord, List <Map <String, Map <String, Monitor.Status>>> servers) {
        Map <String, Map <String, String>> result = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(keyWord, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher keyMatcher;
        Matcher valueMatcher;
        for (Map <String, Map<String, Monitor.Status>> server : servers) {
            Map <String, String> localMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
            boolean haveResult = false;
            Set <String> serverName = server.keySet();
            Optional <String> optional = serverName.stream().findAny();
            String name = optional.get();
            for (Map <String, Monitor.Status> subServer : server.values()) {
                for (Map.Entry<String, Monitor.Status> entry: subServer.entrySet()) {
                    Monitor.Status targetValue = entry.getValue();
                    String targetKey = entry.getKey();
                    keyMatcher = pattern.matcher(targetKey);
                    valueMatcher = pattern.matcher(targetValue.getProblem());
                    if (keyMatcher.find() || valueMatcher.find()) {
                        localMap.put(targetKey, targetValue.getProblem());
                        haveResult = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(haveResult){
                result.put(name, localMap);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: No, writing tests is not possible, unfortunately

Comment: "String name = optional.get () means that I simply take the server name through the lambda

Comment: Check if this `if (keyMatcher.find() || valueMatcher.find())` condition is true at least once, it might be that is never true and `haveResult` is always false hence the `result.put(name, localMap);` line is never reached

Comment: updated the question. Old data is erased, new are added. On the contrary

Answer (score 0):

I found that the same strings came to me in the keys (name). And since the hash map rubs old values that already had the same keys, they were deleted from me. I just swapped the keys and values